# nodeJS - Delayed Job - RoR like ? MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, delayed-job

I'm working on a **nodeJS** API.

I'm searching for a good solution to implement delayed job workers,

---

I have found some possibilities but they don't work with a **mongo** based database (like **Kue**, or **Bull** using **redis**)

---

The goal of this is to monitoring my jobs activities, success failure and retry (and have a page like the `/delayed_jobs` with Ruby on Rails )

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks !

Comment: You can try [agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda) which is designed around mongo. There is also a web interface using [agendash](https://github.com/joeframbach/agendash), which I think is what you mean by `/delayed_jobs`, but I don't know RoR.

Comment: but the problem is that agenda is used like a cron job, not really like a queue of jobs

Comment: Delayed jobs? Can you be more specific on what your are looking for?

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you mean, as I don't know what you're referring to with `/delayed_jobs` and RoR. Agenda tasks don't have to be repeating. You can set them to run `.now()`, and reprocess them in their callback if they fail.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda).
Agenda uses a MongoDB database to persist scheduled tasks